# PostgreSql - Gin Index doesn't help in improving performance

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I am pretty novice in the PostgreSql world.
I store the following JSON objects in the jsonb column of PostgreSQL as one object per row.

```
{"cid":"CID1","Display":"User One CID1","F-Name":"Craig","LName":"One"}
{"cid":"CID1","Display":"User One CID1","F-Name":"Leo","LName":"One"}
{"cid":"CID2","OrderNo":"Ordr One Ord1","O-Name":"Michael","LName":"One"}
{"cid":"CID2","OrderNo":"Ordr One Ord1","O-Name":"Sam","LName":"One"}
{"cid":"CID3","InvocNo":"Invc One Inv1","I-Name":"Ron","LName":"One"}
{"cid":"CID3","InvocNo":"Invc One Inv1","I-Name":"Books","LName":"One"}
```

So these N objects are stored as N rows in a jsonb column (*named as res*). I have a requirement that would query these JSON objects for text match, contains type queries, on Keys ('Display', 'OrderNo', 'InvocNo', F-Name, O-Name etc).
The JSON objects generated are dynamic JSON and the columns (keys) of one JSON object may not be matching to that of another object. I am currently creating a GIN index on res column like below

```
CREATE INDEX gin_idx ON mytable USING gin (res)
```

The performance of filter queries on these columns do not show any improvements while using the GIN index. I have my DB filled with 50,000 rows with such data.

In all these JSON objects only the 'cid' column will be common that would exist in all json objects.

**Which type of index will be best suitable in such scenarios considering that one column/key from JSOn object may not be a part of another object?**

Comment: How do you measure the performance of your queries? Are you using EXPLAIN to show the query plan and look for correct index usage?

Comment: Show us the queries you are using. You index _queries_, not "data".

Comment: Here is the query: select * from tab t 
results->>'cid' = 'CID1' 
where results->>'Display' = 'User One CID1'

Comment: @puneet that's not valid syntax, maybe just a typo? -- try with [operators, which are actually supported by these indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING), like `... WHERE jsonb_column @> '{"Display":"User One CID1"}'`